# react three fiber not showing buffer object

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

i been learning lots about three js with react which use react-three/fiber right now i am learning how to use points to make a simple grid which fill with circle image that i just imported but for some reason it wont render any of the object i been looping from my Points pass too my Buffer Geometry component am quite confused what i did wrong and i didn't see any error in my console or terminal log. can anybody help me by giving a tips or explanation of what i did wrong here, thanks here's my code hope it help.

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Canvas, useLoader} from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import circleImg from "./asset/circle.png";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { useMemo } from 'react';
function Points(){
  const CircleImg = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader,circleImg)
  const count = 100;// number point accross one axis ini akan generate point 10.00 dimana count hanya 100 karena multiply
  const sep = 3; //merupakan distance dari tiap point
  let positions = useMemo(()=>{
    let positions =[] 
    for(let xi=0; xi<count; xi++){
      for(let zi=0; zi<count; zi++){
        let x = sep * (xi - count / 2);
        let z = sep * (zi - count / 2);
        let y = 0;
        positions.push(x,y,z)
      }
    }
    return new Float32Array(positions);//merupakan array yang sesuai dengan buffer
  },[count,sep])//ini dibuat menjadi 1d array dikarenakan bufferAtribute tidak dapat menggunakan 2d array maka dari itu position array akan menjadi seperti [x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x....]
  return (
    <points>
        <bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
          <bufferAttribute 
            attachObject={['attributes','position']}//attribute parameter yang akan dikontrol
            array={positions}
            count={positions.length / 3} //
            itemSize={3}//dikeranakan telah diketahui bahwa tiap arraytype axis akan berisi 3 value pada 1d array
          />
        </bufferGeometry>
        <pointsMaterial attach="material" map={CircleImg}
        color={0x00AAFF}
        sizes={0.5}
        sizeAttenuation //merupakan parameter yang menscale object berdasarkan perspective camera
        transparent={false}
        alphaTest={0.5} //merupakan thresshold saat rendering untuk mencega bila opacity dibawah value alphatest
        opacity={1.0} 
        />
    </points>
  );
}

function AnimationCanvas(){
  return (
    <Canvas camera={{position:[100,10,0],fov:75}}>
    <Suspense fallback={false}>
      <Points/>
    </Suspense>
  </Canvas>
  );
}

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <AnimationCanvas />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems there's a change on attach element on react-three/fiber i fix this code by using this

```
  <bufferGeometry>
    <bufferAttribute
    
       attach="attributes-position" // <- new attributes attach 
    
    />
  </bufferGeometry>
```